# Is there any hacky way to reassign parameter at kotlin

Tags: kotlin, callback, byte-buddy

I'm trying to create java-agent using bytebuddy at kotlin
but i need to reassign function parameter to change the behaviour of the param

The code below give me an error message that being said val cannot be reassign

```
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter(suppress = Throwable::class)
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun enter(
      @Advice.Origin method: String
    , @Advice.Argument(value = 1, readOnly = false) callback: Callback<HttpResponse>
    ) {
      callback = CallbackInterceptor(callback)
    }
  }
```

Is there any hacky way to reassign function parameter at kotlin ?
Or is there any another approach at bytebuddy to achieve this ?

Comment: What's the point of reassigning the parameter? Just use another `val`. E.g. `val callbackInterceptor = CallbackInterceptor(callback)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  — You are aware that even if you _could_ reassign `callback`, it wouldn't affect anything outside that method?  (Parameters are passed by reference, not by name.)

Comment: In Byte Buddy, it does. The byte code is used as a template where the reassignment is translated to an override. This is why such a reassignment is required. I'd recommend to just write the templates in Java where such things are possible.